# Remove required checkbox border in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox, input

If a checkbox is `required`, Firefox will apply a red border to it, even if the form has not yet been submitted. How can I remove or prevent this border?

`<input type='checkbox' required />`

[image]

I tried applying the following styles, none of which worked.

```
input[type=checkbox]:invalid {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:required {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

Now I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: Ahhh, you know what. The `:required` pseudo-class should probably do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red border you are seeing is `box-shadow`. You can set it to `none`.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

[image]

```css
input[type=checkbox]:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" required>
```

Comment: i tried removing the `box-shadow` and it didnt work. forgot to mention that. ill try again tho.

Comment: only tried it on actual element and `required`. youre right tho. using it on `invalid` works!!